# How to retrieve text from response made from Requests python

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to search inside the response of a request (I used Requests and Python). I get the response and check the type of it, which is UNICODE.

I want to retrieve a specific link which is located between two other strings.
I have tried different ways found online such as the:

- `result = re.**search**('Currently: <a ', s)`
- `url_file = response.**find**('Currently: <a ', beg=0, end=len(response))`

Also tried to transform the UNICODE string to a normal string:

- `s = unicodedata.normalize(response, title).encode('ascii','ignore')`

I get an error.

**EDITED**

For example:

This works:

```
    s = 'asdf=5;iwantthis123jasd'
    result = re.search('asdf=5;(.*)123jasd', s)
    print result.group(1)
```

This doesn't work (returns error):

```
    s = 'Currently: <a '
    result = re.search(r.text, s)
    print result.group(1)
```

Comment: Are you looking for `response.text`?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your problem. The text of a response object is stored in the `.text` attribute. Is this a problem you're having with `requests` or with regular expressions and `re` trying to search that text?

Comment: I have response.text. I try to find a specific URL from it. I try to search inside the response.text using the above mentioned functions and I get errors.

Comment: Can you be more specific about *I get errors*? What error you get with which function?

Comment: I added some of my code. Unfortunately I can not specify the error. There must be an issue with the response.text variable.

Comment: Add the traceback, I don't know how you cannot specify the error considering it would be in the traceback. Also you should be using a HTML parser not a regex and your this works and this doesn't work are doing two completely different things. You have passed the text you want to search in the second snippet as the pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `re.search` wrong. The first argument of the function is the pattern and the second one is the source string:

```
import re
import requests

s = '<a class=gb1 href=[^>]+>'
r = requests.get('https://www.google.com/?q=python')
result = re.search(s, r.text)

print result.group(0)
```

If you simply need the list of all matches you can use: `re.findall(s, r.text)`

Answer (score 3):

You can access the raw text from the response object with the `text` attribute.

```
res = requests.get("http://google.com")
re.search('pattern', res.text)
```

Then, just use a regular expression to "search" or "match" the entire response.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.